# Not able to get value out of a datetimepicker to send it through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a datetimepicker on my page which is like this

```
<table class="table borderless" id="schedule_time">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <div id="timepicker" class="form-group" style="width:30%">
          <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" name="date" id="date" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"> <span
                                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now i want to take value of the selected time and send it through an AJAX call to my controller . The problem is i am not able to get the selected date in the datetimepicker .

I have tried

```
var date = $("#datetimepicker1").val();
            alert(date);
var date1 = $("#datetimepicker1").text();
            alert(date1);
```

But these doesn't seem to work . how can i do this

Comment: Get the value of your input element, not of the parent div.

Comment: do you use bootstrap datetimepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of the datetimepicker is **date** so if you want to access its value from javascript you should use `#date` instead of `#datetimepicker1`:

```
var date = $("#date").val();
alert(date);
```